# Relation does not exist - Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

```
    #Create "Game_Platform" Table
    
    try:
        #table_name variable
        game_platformTable="game_platform"
        create_game_platformTablee_query = '''CREATE TABLE '''+ game_platformTable+'''
        (
            id                    INT           NOT NULL,
            game_publiser_id      INT           DEFAULT NULL,
            platform_id           INT           DEFAULT NULL,
            release_year          INT           DEFAULT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (id),
            FOREIGN KEY (game_pulisher_id) REFERENCES game_publisher(publisher_id), 
            FOREIGN KEY (platform_id) REFERENCES platform(id)
            );'''
    
        #Execute this command (SQL Query)
        cursor.execute(create_game_platformTablee_query)
    
    # Make the changes to the database persistent
    con.commit()
    print("Table ("+ game_platformTable +") created successfully in PostgreSQL ")
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    # if it exits with an exception the transaction is rolled back.
    con.rollback()
    print("Error While Creating the DB: ",error)
```

ERROR I get

```
Error While Creating the DB:  relation "gameplatform" does not exist
```

This is the only table that won't work for me. I cannot see why this is happening. My talble is not even called gameplatform it's called game_platform. Any tips? This is very frustrating

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please check your spelling. You have a field named `game_publiser_id`, and you're trying to set up a foreign key reference for `game_pulisher_id`. Neither is spelled correctly and they don't match each other. I can't reproduce the error you're asking about.